# Problem with Maximize

Tags: functions, programming, warning-messages

As $\{p1,p2,p3,p4,p5\}$ represents a probability distribution and $l1,l2$ are the eigenvalues of a stochastic matrix, the function $f$, as defined below, has to be maximized over a certain region.

```
L[p_List] := (p[[1]] - 0.2)*Log[p[[1]]] + (p[[2]] - 0.2)*
Log[p[[2]]] + (p[[3]] - 0.2)*Log[p[[3]]] + (p[[4]] - 0.2)*
Log[p[[4]]] + (p[[5]] - 0.2)*Log[p[[5]]]

CirculantMatrix[l_List?VectorQ] := 
NestList[RotateRight, RotateRight[l], Length[l] - 1]
CirculantMatrix[l_List?VectorQ, n_Integer] := 
NestList[RotateRight, 
RotateRight[Join[Table[0, {n - Length[l]}], l]], n - 1] /; 
n >= Length[l]

invFou[l_List] := 0.2*{1 + 2 l[[1]] Cos[2 Pi/5] + 2 l[[2]] Cos[4 Pi/5], 
1 + 2 l[[1]] Cos[4 Pi/5] + 2 l[[2]] Cos[2 Pi/5], 
1 + 2 l[[1]] Cos[4 Pi/5] + 2 l[[2]] Cos[2 Pi/5], 
1 + 2 l[[1]] Cos[2 Pi/5] + 2 l[[2]] Cos[4 Pi/5], 
1 + 2 l[[1]] + 2 l[[2]]}

m[l_List] := CirculantMatrix[invFou[l]]

f[p_List, M_List] := L[p.m[M]]/L[p]
```

We may assume that $l1=0.5$ and $0.37\leq l2 \leq 0.5$. If we try

```
Maximize[{f[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}, {0.5, 
l2}], {p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 == 1 && p1 >= 0 && p2 >= 0 && 
p3 >= 0 && p4 >= 0 && p5 >= 0 && 0.37 <= l2 <= 0.5}}, {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, l2}]
```

we get an error:

> NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -0.206184-0.256075 I is not a real number at {l2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5} = {0.446053,-0.0362605,0.263705,0.324533,0.369047,0.0789762}. >>

Why doesn't *Mathematica* take the maximum over the specified region?

Comment: If your function is sufficiently messy, you may need to try using `FindMaximum` instead, noting that it finds local maxima, depending on where you start the search. But then, `NMaximize` may also yield local maxima.

Answer (score 6):

The docs specify that the domain should (usually) be `Reals` or `Integers`.  These are keywords. You probably want the "domain" to be specified as a constraint.

```
Maximize[{
  Abs[f[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}, {0.5, l2}]],
  {p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 == 1 && p1 >= 0 && p2 >= 0 && p3 >= 0 && p4 >= 0 &&
   p5 >= 0 && 0 <= l2 <= 0.5}},
 {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, l2}]
```

Or in V10 you can use the new region functions to specify the domain.

```
Maximize[
 {Abs[f[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}, {0.5, l2}]]},
 {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, l2} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[
   p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 == 1 && p1 >= 0 && p2 >= 0 && p3 >= 0 && 
    p4 >= 0 && p5 >= 0 && 0 <= l2 <= 0.5, {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, l2}]]
```

With a capriciously chosen objective function

```
f[p_, l_] := p.p - Flatten[{1, l, l}].p
```

both of the above return

```
{0.45,
 {p1 -> 0.4, p2 -> 0.149999, p3 -> 0.150002, p4 -> 0.149999, p5 -> 0.150002, l2 -> 0.5}}
```

Comment: I tried your last suggestion. Unfortunately, I get another error: 

NMaximize::nnum: The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {l2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5} = {0.482834,-0.218535,0.398641,0.613972,0.205921,0.}. >>

For some reason Mathematica doesn't maximize the function over the specified region.

Comment: @phil Which function did you try? My `f` above evaluates to `0.245845` at `{l2,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5} = {0.482834,-0.218535,0.398641,0.613972,0.205921,0.}`, not `Indeterminate`. (No one else can test your function, since you haven't posted it. The problem is probably dependent on your `f`.)